# ReactJS: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressLine1' of undefined at fetch.then.then.json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I recently started learning ReactJS so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to send entered address to a normalization service that will return the address in the normalized format. I have nested states which explains why I'm using immutability helper to create an object, modify it and then set it to the nested state. The call to the service was working just fine until I changed to nested states and now it's giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressLine1' of undefined at fetch.then.then.json
```

Here's my fetch function:

```
fetchAddress: function() {
console.log("componentDidMount function entered");

var data = JSON.stringify({
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": this.state.address.addressLine1,
    "addressLine2": this.state.address.addressLine2,
    "city": this.state.address.city,
    "state": this.state.address.state,
    "postalCode": this.state.address.postalCode
  }
});

var component = this;

fetch("http://localhost:8080/address/validate", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: data
}).then((response)=>{
  return response.json()
}).then((json) => {
  var obj = this.state.validAddress;
  var validAddress = update(obj, {
    addressLine1: {$set: json.address.addressLine1},
    addressLine2: {$set: json.address.addressLine1},
    city: {$set: json.address.city},
    state: {$set: json.address.state},
    postalCode: {$set: json.address.postalCode}
  });
  component.setState({validAddress});
});
```

}

Any kind of help would be great! Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I found out the problem and it was the way my data was being sent. this.state.address.variable returned an array with one string variable, instead of just the string variable, which caused problems with the normalization service.

Comment: the json object doesnt have an address property which return undefined and trying to access addressLine1 `json.address.addressLine1` on undefined will throw. check the api result for the address property

Comment: My bad for not specifying this but the returned format is like the following: {
    "status": 0,
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "",
        "addressLine2": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "postalCode": ""
    }
}

Comment: try console log your json abject.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(json.address.addressLine1)`

Comment: I tried console log my json object and this came out: Object {timestamp: 1500657654584, status: 400, error: "Bad Request", exception: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException", message: "Could not read document: Can not deserialize. So I'm thinking it's not the code that's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Object is in json, so you need to convert it first.

To convert an object to a string, use JSON.stringify:

`var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);`

In your case 
`JSON.stringify(json.address.addressLine1)`